# How do I upload a file using Bootstrap4 custom file upload via ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm struggling to get a file to upload. I've checked a dozen samples here (copied code verbatim) and nothing works. I get no errors, no upload, I just get nothing.

I set a breakpoint in my controller but it doesn't get hit. All my code is below, what am I doing wrong

I'm using asp.net.core 2.2 and VS2019

HTML

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h4>Import Users</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <form id="frmUpload" action="@Url.Action("PerformImportUsers","Admin")" method="post">
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="custom-file">
                            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="importFile" id="inputGroupFile02">
                            <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile02" style="overflow:hidden;">Choose file</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <a href="" class="input-group-text btn btn-primary" id="uploadFile"><span class="fa fa-upload"></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
    $("#uploadFile").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //e.stopPropagation();

        debugger;
        var myForm = $("#frmUpload");
        var sUrl = myForm.attr("action");

        var files = $("#inputGroupFile02").get(0);
        var formData = new FormData();

        for (var i = 0; i != files.length; i++) {
            formData.append("myfile", files[i]);
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: sUrl,            
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formData,
            success: function (result) {    
                var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                showNotify(data.message);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("there was an error");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

CONTROLLER

```
    [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult PerformImportUsers(List<IFormFile> importFile)
    {
        return new JsonResult(new { result = "success", message = "Uploaded" });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To upload a file your `form` tag needs `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Try adding that and you should see the file come through in the back end.

And remove that javascript, that is not needed.

Comment: I'm sorry, which javascript do I need to remove ?

Comment: You guys are freakin awesome. I'm sure I tried some combination of these, just didn't have the right combination. Thanks, loads All :)

Comment: @djack109 all of it! :-) great to hear you got it working anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
    [HttpPost]
        //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public JsonResult PerformImportUsers() // remove parameter
        {
             var files = this.Request.Form.Files; //retreive files
            return new JsonResult(new { result = "success", message = "Uploaded" });
        }
```

Besides this code below will only add 1 file

```
for (var i = 0; i != files.length; i++) {
            formData.append("myfile", files[i]); // change it to "myfile"+i
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, press `F12` in browser to check the `action` (sUrl) is correct or not,it should be `action="/Admin/PerformImportUsers"`.

Then change your js to below to upload files using formdata.You need to match name of formData to the parameter name (`importFile`)on `POST` method.

```
<script>
    $("#uploadFile").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var myForm = $("#frmUpload");
        var sUrl = myForm.attr("action");

        var input = document.getElementById("inputGroupFile02");
        var files = input.files;
        var formData = new FormData();

        for (var i = 0; i != files.length; i++) {
            formData.append("importFile", files[i]);
        }


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: sUrl,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formData,
            success: function (result) {
                var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                showNotify(data.message);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("there was an error");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```